# How to set multiple patterns for Laravel 4 route?

Tags: laravel, laravel-4

I had this piece of route in a project in Laravel 3:

```
Route::get(array('/Home', '/'.rawurlencode ('خانه')), function()
{
    return View::make('home.index');
});
```

It was working correctly, till I decided to migrate it to Laravel 4. Now in Laravel 4 I get this error:

`preg_match_all() expects parameter 2 to be string, array given`

Are there any other way to set multiple patterns for Laravel 4 route?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can achieve this using `where` with your route,

So if your route is,

```
Route::get('{home}', function()
{
    return View::make('home.index');
})->where('خانه', '(home)?');
```

You can access the same using,

```
http://localhost/laravel/home
http://localhost/laravel/خانه
```

Here the `http://localhost/laravel/` should be replaced with yours.

Using `regex` is the best way,

```
Route::get('{home}', function()
{
    return View::make('home.index');
})->where('home', '(home|خانه)');
```

This will match only,

```
http://localhost/laravel/home
http://localhost/laravel/خانه
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use regex in the route so maybe something like this.

```
Route::get('(Home|' . rawurlencode('خانه') . ')', function ()
{
    return View::make('home.index');
});
```

If that doesn't work I'd probably just define two route's because the closure is so simple. Even if it is more complex, you could move it to a controller and point two routes at the same controller method.

Comment: Thanks buddy! Unfortunately it didn't work... But Devo's solution was great... :)